Newton-Raphson Comparison to Power World
I am hoping someone can help me adjust my calculations & help me have a deeper understanding of why there exists a discrepancy between my calculations and results from Power World Software.
A little background: I am self learning basic power flow calculations for power systems. I've started with simple two bus systems: one slack and one constant impedance/PQ/PV bus.
My approaches to calculating for the constant impedance / PQ bus power flows had very little error when compared to Power World. However, when I got to the PV bus, my calculations had more error compared to Power World. In general, both my calculation and Power World follow similar trends, just with greater difference between the two than the other two bus types.
Note: The majority of this discussion is only focusing on the phase angle of the voltage on the second bus, before I go and calculate the rest of the parameters.
Calculating the phase angle:
I start off by deriving the 1-dimensional Jacobian of the power of bus two with respect to the bus angle.
$$
\frac{\partial P_{2}}{\partial\delta_{2}}=-V_{2} \sum_{n=1,n\neq 2}^2 Y_{2n} V_{n}\sin(\delta_2-\delta_n-\theta_{2n})
=-V_{2}V_{1}Y_{21}\sin(\delta_2-\delta_1-\theta_{21})
$$
where \$Y\$ and \$\theta\$ are the admittance parameters, \$V_i\$ and \$\delta_i\$ are the respective bus voltage.
For this scenario, I am assuming both bus voltages have a magnitude of 1, and the slack bus angle is 0. So, this simplifies slightly to
$$
\frac{\partial P_2}{\partial\delta_2}=-Y_{21}\sin(\delta_{2,i}-\theta_{21})
$$
I then derive \$\Delta y_i=y-P_{2}(x_{i})\$ as follows:
$$
\Delta y_i = P_2 - V_2 \sum_{n=1}^{2}{Y_{2n}V_{n}\cos(\delta_{2,i}-\delta_{1}-\theta_{2n})}
=P_2 - V_2 (Y_{21} V_{1} \cos(\delta_{2,i} - \delta_{1}-\theta_{21}) + Y_{22} V_{2} \cos(\delta_{2,i } - \delta_{2,i}-\theta_{22}))
$$
Similar to before, the bus voltages are one and the slack bus angle is zero. The above becomes
$$
\Delta y_i = P_2-Y_{21} \cos(\delta_{2,i}-\theta_{21}) - Y_{22} \cos(-\theta_{22})
$$
The linearization is \$ \Delta y_i = J(x_i) \Delta \delta_{2,i} \$ Plugging in our findings gives
$$
P_2-Y_{21} \cos(\delta_{2,i}-\theta_{21}) - Y_{22} \cos(-\theta_{22}) 
= -Y_{21}\sin(\delta_{2,i}-\theta_{21})\Delta \delta_{2,i}
$$
\$\Delta \delta_{2,i} = \delta_{2,i+1}-\delta_{2,i}\$, so taking the inverse of the Jacobian and adding \$ \delta_{2,i}\$ on both sides gives the final equation:
$$
\delta_{2,i+1}=\frac{P_2-Y_{21} \cos(\delta_{2,i}-\theta_{21}) - Y_{22} \cos(-\theta_{22})}{-Y_{21}\sin(\delta_{2,i}-\theta_{21})}+\delta_{2,i}
$$
Now, to compare this result with Power World, I assume a transmission line of impedance \$0.05 + j0.05\$ pu and vary the generated power.
With this transmission line impedance, I get the admittance matrices
$$
Y=\begin{pmatrix} 10\sqrt{2} & 10\sqrt{2} \\ 10\sqrt{2} & 10\sqrt{2} \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\theta=\begin{pmatrix} -45° & 135° \\ 135° & -45° \end{pmatrix}
$$
So, plugging these back into the equation for \$\delta_{2,i+1}\$, I get
$$
\delta_{2,i+1}=\frac{(10-P_2) + 10\sqrt{2} \cos(\delta_{2,i}-135°)}{10\sqrt{2}\sin(\delta_{2,i}-135°)}+\delta_{2,i}
$$
Comparison to Power World:
Now, with \$P_2=1\; pu\$ and a few iterations of the above equation I get 5.47°. But, when simulating this in Power World, I get about 4.9° as shown below, which means my current calculation, for example, varies about 50 A.

As \$P_2\$ gets smaller, this error seems to become larger, with \$P_2=10\,\mathrm{MW}\$ according to my equation having \$\delta_2=0.57°\$, but Power World giving me \$\delta_2\approx 0\$ as shown below

The opposite seems true, as \$P_2\$ get's larger, the error seems smaller. For example, with \$P_2=1000\,\mathrm{MW}\$ I get 45° from the equation and Power World outputs 44.59° as shown below.

Perhaps this error is roughly constant, so the relative error as angle increases is less noticeable, but for smaller angles is it larger? I am not sure why this is happening, nor how to adjust my calculations to get closer values between the two.
For reference, my transmission line, generator, and slack settings are shown below



